# Why don't my sprites animate when I add a self.image in update function?

Tags: python, animation, sprite, pyglet

I'm currrently learning pyglet, and there is a teeny problem. I called a superclass of the init of pyglet.sprite.Sprite in my player class, but when I try to change the self.image from the update function (or any function that is not the **init**), it doesn't animate anymore, in fact, it just displays the first element in the array conatining the images for my animation. Thanks. Here is are my codes:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key
import physicalobject, resources

class Player(physicalobject.PhysicalObject): #PhysicalObject is just another pyglet.sprite.Sprite superclass
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Player,self).__init__(img=resources.right_anim, *args, **kwargs)
        # some codes here....
    def update(self, dt):
        super(Player,self).update(dt)
        #... codes
        if self.look_right:
            self.image = resources.right_anim
        elif self.look_left:
            self.image = resources.left_anim
```

Comment: which pyglet version are you using?